# presenting a viewcontroller modally covering only half screen AND having navigation controller working on top of the page

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a view controller that is being presented modally and only covering half bottom of the page. Now I want to be able to dismiss this preferably by having a cancel type of button on the navigation bar on top of the page. 
How could I achieve this?

I have seen a lot of post on modally presenting a page , even half size , but none addresses getting the navigation bar on top.

Below is how I present the view controller modally; I have tried adding a UINavigationController but that changes the whole thing and present the view full screen again.

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mymodallyview" ) as! MyViewController    
vc.transitioningDelegate = self
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.custom

 //when adding UINavigation controller it will present full screen
 //  let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc) 

 self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you give an image?

Comment: you mean image of what I want? I don't have any at the moment, it's just a half screen modally presented view controller on the bottom and still the navigation controller where it normally is on top

Comment: Hmm...i cant really imagine, you mean it have nav bar at the very top like normal view, while the view itself only cover half and see through?

Comment: It should work if you use IB to embed `MyViewController` within a `UINavigationController` on the Main storyboard. Your commented out code looks like it's trying to add it to one on the fly.

Comment: Yes, well there's the parent view controller behind all of this so you the top half of the screen that is not covered by the modally presented view still shows the parent view controller..

Comment: @Michael Yes, I saw that adding the nav bar like what I did (commented out) is the solution , but when I do that the modally presented view covers the full screen and kinda ignores everything that I do to force it to be half screen

Comment: maybe I need to rethink this ...

Comment: I have done this before by designing a full-size screen for the modal, but ensuring the bottom half is transparent so you can "see through" to the original screen.

Comment: @Michael , right, I am just trying to reuse some of my controllers and well changing the design and enforce all that changes might not actually help as I'm just writing more codes .. Yet, might be a good idea , gotta try, thanks again, 
the real problem is that I have some animation going on on the back ground so it kinda look weird to have a nav bar appearing if you know what I mean

Comment: I guess easiest way is to just do some delegation and forget the nav bar

Comment: Now I"m thinking what happens to that empty half screen when a controller is presented modally on half screen?

Comment: Forgive me, but read the first three sentences on this [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window Wikipedia link. By definition, a **modal** window forces a user to do something in that popup before allowing the main view underneath to be "enabled".

Comment: @dfd , I understand that and am not asking to do something on the parent view controller , just need the child to be half size and have a nav bar as well

Comment: I'd think that since the nav bar is part of your app, that's considered beneath the modal popup also. I could be wrong though... is there an app out there that does what you want? Back in the day (when I worked with SAP) that was always my favorite question. If I could be shown that it can be done I'd figure out a way to do it.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I'm rethinking the whole thing, I am starting to think it won't be a good practice to have such a thing. But now am just more curious as to how this could be done if it is possible